# Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, terminal, appium

I want to run a java project in terminal. When I compiled, no error occurred, but when I run the program I get the following error:

> Could not find or load main class `or`Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Appium (wrong name:
>   com/appiumproj/test/Appium)

Please help me to solve this problem.

```
iMac:~ Samuel$ javac -cp /Users/Samuel/Downloads/AppiumTest/lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar:/Users/Samuel/Downloads/AppiumTest/lib/gson-2.3.1.jar:/Users/Samuel/Downloads/AppiumTest/lib/java-client-2.2.0.jar: /Users/Samuel/Downloads/AppiumTest/src/com/appiumproj/test/Appium.java 
iMac:~ Samuel$ java -cp  /Users/Samuel/Downloads/AppiumTest/lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar:/Users/Samuel/Downloads/AppiumTest/lib/gson-2.3.1.jar:/Users/Samuel/Downloads/AppiumTest/lib/java-client-2.2.0.jar: /Users/Samuel/Downloads/AppiumTest/src/com/appiumproj/test/Appium
Error: Could not find or load main class .Users.Samuel.Downloads.AppiumTest.src.com.appiumproj.test.Appium
iMac:~ Samuel$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the *name* of the class - not a filename. It needs to be the fully-qualified class name, and it needs to be on the classpath. So after compiling, you'd want something like this (just spread out on multiple lines for readability; the backslashes are line continuations - you should be able to copy and paste this straight into your shell):

```
java -cp  /Users/Samuel/Downloads/AppiumTest/lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar\
:/Users/Samuel/Downloads/AppiumTest/lib/gson-2.3.1.jar\
:/Users/Samuel/Downloads/AppiumTest/lib/java-client-2.2.0.jar\
:/Users/Samuel/Downloads/AppiumTest/src \
com.appiumproj.test.Appium
```

Comment: @YosuvaA: Just use `;` instead of `:` - and put it all on one line, removing the backslashes

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your compiled version is in /Users/Samuel/Downloads/AppiumTest/src/com/appiumproj/test/ ? I would say that it is probably where the javac was run. Check and find it and specify the path to to compile version